# Any good CSS3 shadow tutorials, plugins or examples?

Tags: shadow, css

I'm joining together a huge list of CSS3 shadows that will include tutorials, plugins, scripts and more. I have discarded all the other search methods and I have found some pretty cool things, but still I'm sure that I can find even greater things here, thanks :)...

Comment: You've *discarded* all the other search methods? <voice impersonate="Inigo Montoya">I do not think that word means what you think it means.</voice>

Answer (score 1):

[This is a good one](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/)

Comment: Yay for one link and no explanation answers!

Comment: He's specifically asking for links to tutorials. Thanks for the snide comment.

Comment: What I meant was: Wouldn't this whole question and all its possible answers serve a better purpose for the OP, the readers and the whole site if you could immediately see code and upvote that instead of having to browse through numerous links? What if any of the tutorial pages goes down?

Comment: Thanks Steve, that's a nice resource!. Slhck is right when he says that many sites could be down in the future, however I'm already making the list this way, I have found great snippets and tutorials so far, hopefully you can help me find more before I publish the article...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this tool is useful: http://www.css3.me/

You can do some nice css3 stuff on an html div with some sliders and options. You can see right away what you are doing. When your done you can generate the source code and use it on your own website.